# Type-safely pass a class name to a method

Tags: c#, class, type-safety

I need the class name in a method say for example X. Meanwhile, I don't want to loose type-safety and I'm not gonna allow other developers to pass a string (class name) to the method.

Something like this:

```
void X( ??? class) // --> don't know how
{
 var className = get the name of class // --> which I don't know how
 Console.WriteLine(className);
}

X(tblEmployee); //--> usage of X, where tblEmployee is a POCO class
```

Answer (score 15):

What you are looking for is a called a [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx), which contains metadata about classes.

You can use the [`typeof(class)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [`.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) method on any `object` instance.

The different is that `typeof` is resolved statically and `GetType` is resolved at runtime.

```
void X(Type type)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
}

X(typeof(tblEmployee));
```

Comment: Since tblEmployee is a class not an object, X(tblEmployee.GetType()) is wrong because GetType() can be called on objects. Instead X(typeof(tblEmployee)) is correct.

Comment: @Alireza Sorry, I thought it was an instance of the class. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

You could use generics and the [`FullName` property of `Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx), as such:

```
void WriteClassName<TClass>(TClass item)
  where TClass : class {
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetType().FullName);
}
```

And then apply contraints on `TClass` as per your requirements.

Comment: We need to pass Type and not the object. In this case the method will accept object of type TClass. I don't thing this is what we want...

Answer (score 1):

```
void X(Type type)
{
    if(type == typeof(DesiredType))
    {
          Do Some Action
    }
}
```